# Invalid file index 14 in filtergraph description - FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video, concatenation

I am getting error in my command saying: Invalid file index 14 in filtergraph description

But I am seeing teh correct count and inputs. What indx I am doing wrong. Please can you advise me.

Below is my comamnd. I have formated it so that it can be understandable.

Command below:

```
ffmpeg 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeSameMediaAudioVideo_1_5157.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_2_8955.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtSameVideo_3_7749.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeSameMediaAudioVideo_3_1137.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_4_7035.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtExternalVideo_5_1560.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeExternalMediaAudioVideo_5_3387.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_6_5929.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtSameVideo_7_3635.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeSameMediaAudioVideo_7_2726.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_8_6239.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtExternalVideo_9_9862.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeExternalMediaAudioVideo_9_9464.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21//SSLK006998_1535.mp4 
-filter_complex "
[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=386.1[V01];
[V01][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=522.05[V02];
[V02][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=961.22[V03];
[V03][4]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=1347.32[V04];
[V04][5]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=1559.07[V05];
[V05][6]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=2180.17[V06];
[V06][7]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=2248.67[V07];
[V07][8]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=2724.96[V08];
[V08][9]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=3376.38[V09];
[V09][10]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=3762.48[V010];
[V010][11]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=3936.33[V011];
[V011][12]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=4580.17[V012];
[V012][13]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=4648.67[V013];
[V013][14]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=5056.74,format=yuv420p[video]; 
[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A01];
[A01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A02];
[A02][3:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A03];
[A03][4:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A04];
[A04][5:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A05];
[A05][6:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A06];
[A06][7:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A07];
[A07][8:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A08];
[A08][9:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A09];
[A09][10:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A010];
[A010][11:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A011];
[A011][12:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A012];
[A012][13:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A013];
[A013][14:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri:c2=tri[audio]" 

-map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_FinalMergedFile_NotFromAction_9415.mp4
```

Error details below:

```
Invalid file index 14 in filtergraph description [0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=386.1[V01];[V01][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=522.05[V02];[V02][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=961.22[V03];[V03][4]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=1347.32[V04];[V04][5]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=1559.07[V05];[V05][6]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=2180.17[V06];[V06][7]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=2248.67[V07];[V07][8]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=2724.96[V08];[V08][9]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=3376.38[V09];[V09][10]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=3762.48[V010];[V010][11]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=3936.33[V011];[V011][12]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=4580.17[V012];[V012][13]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=4648.67[V013];[V013][14]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=5056.74,format=yuv420p[video]; [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A01];[A01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A02];[A02][3:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A03];[A03][4:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A04];[A04][5:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A05];[A05][6:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A06];[A06][7:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A07];[A07][8:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A08];[A08][9:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A09];[A09][10:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A010];[A010][11:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A011];[A011][12:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A012];[A012][13:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A013];[A013][14:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri:c2=tri[audio].
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I count 14 inputs and ffmpeg indexes from 0, so 13 is the index for the last input.

Comment: Thanks, seems it is working. I am waiting for final output. Getting other errors. Changes are done at url: https://superuser.com/questions/1650734/error-while-filtering-cannot-allocate-memory-ffmpeg once I see the final output I will accept the solution. Looks it is working fine. Please see in the url provided that changes I made is ok. Thanks.

Comment: That's a different question.

Comment: Ok. I think I am fine with this. Kind Regards. See if you can help me on other one. Thanks again.