# Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory - FFMPEG

Tags: memory, ffmpeg, video

Now I am trying to bring multiple effects to 2 videos only. I have removed other videos for now to test.

I am getting error "Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory"

Command below:

```
ffmpeg -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_1_6178.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_2_3675.mp4 

-filter_complex 
" [0][0]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=712.06[V00];
[V00][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=1522.67,format=yuv420p[video];
[0:a][0:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A00];
[A00][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" 

-map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart 
D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_FinalMergedFile_NotFromAction_4882.mp4
```

Offset calculation below:
[image: Offset calculation here]

Error details below:

```
ffmpeg -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_1_6178.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_2_3675.mp4 -filter_complex " [0][0]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=712.06[V00];[V00][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=1522.67,format=yuv420p[video]; [0:a][0:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A00];[A00][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_FinalMergedFile_NotFromAction_4882.mp4
ffmpeg version 2021-05-09-git-8649f5dca6-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavcodec     59.  1.100 / 59.  1.100
  libavformat    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavdevice    59.  0.100 / 59.  0.100
  libavfilter     8.  0.101 /  8.  0.101
  libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_1_6178.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:11:52.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3468 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3272 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_2_3675.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:13:31.19, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3588 kb/s
  Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3393 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> xfade:main
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> acrossfade:crossfade0
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> acrossfade:crossfade1
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> acrossfade:crossfade1
  format -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  acrossfade -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] 264 - core 163 r3059 b684ebe - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_FinalMergedFile_NotFromAction_4882.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top coded first (swapped)), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.1.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.1.100 aac
Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memoryme=00:02:54.37 bitrate=5435.9kbits/s speed=1.55x
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] frame I:24    Avg QP:19.38  size:211131
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] frame P:1108  Avg QP:22.51  size: 65649
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] frame B:3195  Avg QP:26.66  size: 11943
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] consecutive B-frames:  1.0%  1.0%  2.1% 95.9%
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] mb I  I16..4: 14.1% 70.4% 15.5%
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] mb P  I16..4:  3.1%  9.1%  1.2%  P16..4: 39.2% 15.0%  9.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:23.4%
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.5%  0.0%  B16..8: 36.3%  3.2%  0.7%  direct: 2.0%  skip:57.1%  L0:41.9% L1:50.4% BI: 7.7%
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] 8x8 transform intra:68.2% inter:73.3%
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 53.6% 53.3% 18.0% inter: 13.8% 12.3% 0.6%
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] i16 v,h,dc,p: 36% 30%  9% 24%
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 16% 28%  3%  4%  5%  4%  5%  5%
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 46% 11%  3%  4%  4%  4%  4%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] i8c dc,h,v,p: 50% 19% 25%  6%
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.1% UV:1.4%
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] ref P L0: 58.3% 14.1% 21.4%  6.1%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] ref B L0: 88.6%  9.5%  1.9%
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] ref B L1: 94.5%  5.5%
[libx264 @ 0000024251c40480] kb/s:5360.09
[aac @ 00000242510a3500] Qavg: 482.511
[aac @ 00000242510a3500] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

Please advise.

Kind Regards,

Commad giving Invalid file index error:

```
ffmpeg -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_1_7435.mp4 
 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_2_7575.mp4 
 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtSameVideo_3_3142.mp4 
 
 -filter_complex " [0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=712.06[V01];
 [V01][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=1522.67[V02];
 [V02][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=2583.43,format=yuv420p[video]; 
 [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A01];
 [A01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A02];
 [A02][3:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" 
 
 -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_FinalMergedFile_NotFromAction_8821.mp4
```

Complete logs as requested:

```
ffmpeg  -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_1_7435.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_2_7575.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtSameVideo_3_3142.mp4 -filter_complex " [0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=712.06[V01];[V01][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=1522.67[V02];[V02][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=2583.43,format=yuv420p[video]; [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A01];[A01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A02];[A02][3:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_FinalMergedFile_NotFromAction_8821.mp4
ffmpeg version 2021-05-09-git-8649f5dca6-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavcodec     59.  1.100 / 59.  1.100
  libavformat    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavdevice    59.  0.100 / 59.  0.100
  libavfilter     8.  0.101 /  8.  0.101
  libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_1_7435.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:11:52.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3468 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3272 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_2_7575.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:13:31.19, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3588 kb/s
  Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3393 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtSameVideo_3_3142.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:17:41.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3679 kb/s
  Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3483 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Invalid file index 3 in filtergraph description  [0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=712.06[V01];[V01][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=1522.67[V02];[V02][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=2583.43,format=yuv420p[video]; [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A01];[A01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A02];[A02][3:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio].
```

Comment: Where are the error details? Looks like you have posted the same thing (command) twice. How large (file size) are the 7 input video files?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the error details in main question. I have edited the question. Please advise. Kind Regards,

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: HIi, I have re-ran the code which has generated new set of files. Updated command and full logs. I have edited the orignal question. Please advise. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi, I have now removed multiple videos to test and even 2 videos are also giving same error. I have updated my main question and added offset calculation. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same input file for the first xfade filter. Instead of using `[0][0]xfade`, add the same file as another input and use `[0][1]xfade`. It may require less memory.

```
ffmpeg -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_1_6178.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_1_6178.mp4 
-i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_2_3675.mp4 

-filter_complex 
" [0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=712.06[V00];
[V00][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=1522.67,format=yuv420p[video];
[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A00];
[A00][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" 

-map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart 
D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_FinalMergedFile_NotFromAction_4882.mp4
```

Comment: Many thanks @llogan, I tried this before and tried again. I am getting the Invalid file index error as explained in question: https://superuser.com/questions/1650697/invalid-file-index-14-in-filtergraph-description-ffmpeg/1650718?noredirect=1#comment2525374_1650718 . I tried again then I am getting the same error even with 3 files. Please advise. Many thanks again for your help.

Comment: @D.B. Show your command and complete log.

Comment: Many thanks @llogan, My script and logs edited in this question. Please advise. Kind Regards.

Comment: @D.B. This is a completely different issue unrelated to the this particular question and answer regarding `Cannot allocate memory`. Your command is now different and no longer refer to the same input multiple times. This new issue is the same as your other question [Invalid file index 14 in filtergraph description - FFMPEG](https://superuser.com/q/1650697/). You have 3 inputs. ffmpeg starts counting from 0. So `[3]` would refer to input 4, but you don't have 4 inputs. You are trying to do 3 xfade and 3 acrossfade, but 3 files only need 2 xfade/acrossfade: `input 0<xfade>input1<xfade>input2`.

Comment: Not sure how to thank you. You solved my problem I am very grateful to you.  Many Many thanks