# ffmpeg Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm using Plex as my DVR and I have a process that uses ffmpeg to convert the recordings to a standard format and reduces the size. I've recently been getting the following error:

```
Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[aac @ 0x55b1c3edd7c0] Qavg: 388.931
[aac @ 0x55b1c3edd7c0] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

Here is the command it's using:

`ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -i /media/video.ts -max_muxing_queue_size 8000 -map 0:0 -c:v:0 hevc_vaapi -vf fps=25,scale_vaapi=format=p010 -b:v 4147200 -map 0:1 -c:a:0 aac -b:a 384000 -map_metadata:g -1 -metadata JBDONEVERSION=1 -metadata JBDONEDATE=2021-12-23T23:57:44.168Z -map_chapters 0 /temp/video-IYU7Rix9M.mkv`

I have a solid machine with an i7 9th generation processor, 32GB of RAM, and plenty of storage.

Edit: Adding additional info, is there anything else that will help?

Video file is: .ts
Codec is: mpeg2video
Filesize: 1-3GB

Plex removes commercials before I process them to shrink/standardize them.

Comment: Check the following post: [Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory - FFMPEG](https://superuser.com/q/1650734/1266966)

Comment: @Jackdaw thank you! I saw that before but didn't think it applied to my situation. I re-reviewed it and they were saying it was something with the video filter settings. So i tried messing with my command. Removing the fps=25 (resetting the frame rate) resolved the issue and lets me process the file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user @Jackdaw I found that it was the part of the ffmpeg command that was reducing the framerate to 25. I modified my command to remove the fps=25 and it works now.

The command to process them successfully is:

`ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -i /media/video.ts -max_muxing_queue_size 8000 -map 0:0 -c:v:0 hevc_vaapi -vf scale_vaapi=format=p010 -b:v 4147200 -map 0:1 -c:a:0 aac -b:a 384000 -map_metadata:g -1 -metadata JBDONEVERSION=1 -metadata JBDONEDATE=2021-12-23T23:57:44.168Z -map_chapters 0 /temp/video-IYU7Rix9M.mkv`